# IntelliJ can't find tests if package name exists in src/main/java

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, junit-jupiter

I'm trying to introduce Unit tests to our system, and have run into a problem with Junit not finding test.
I have these 3 tests:

[image]

When I run all tests in the module:

[image]

It finds X and Y tests, but not Z:

[image]

The difference between the 3 is only in the package name:

- The package `com.exlibris.x` (XTest) doesn't exist in the project
- The package `com.exlibris.core.infra.svc.api.flags` (YTest) exists in a different module in the project (that is outputted to a different jar file)
- The package `com.exlibris.repository.web.mms.publishing` (ZTest) exists in the same module under the src/main/java

My pom.xml has the following dependencies (inherited from the parent pom):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

EDIT: These are my run configurations

[image]

[image]

Comment: First use the junit-bom file ...and also use most recent version of surefire-plugin... (More details: https://youtu.be/NVvMzy0Lin0) Also see real example project: https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/tree/main/episode-2 btw. It's not clear what you mean by: `with Junit not finding test`??

Comment: For the existing packages you must cleanly separate between your production code `src/main/java/<package>` and your test code `src/test/java/<package>` ...

Comment: I mean that I have 3 Test classes but it only runs the tests from 2 of them. If I remove those 2 and run tests I get "No tests were found"

Comment: @khmarbaise
Anyway, I replaced the dependencies in dependencyManagement with the junit-bom and upgraded surefire from 3.0.0-M4 to 3.0.0-M8 and I get the same issue.

Comment: can you upload the screenshot of your Run Config for this run?

Comment: Regarding the separation, I have a production class in `src/main/java/my/package/Z.java` and I have 3 test classes. The ones in `src/test/java/other/package` work, but `src/test/java/my/package/ZTest.java` isn't being run

Comment: @quickfix I added the configurations

Comment: Does it work when run directly by maven? If not, it's likely an issue with your pom(s), if maven executes all tests but intellij doesn't, refreshing (or reimporting) the project into intellij might help.

Comment: Thanks @KathrinGeilmann :)

It didn't work when run directly by Maven either, but your comment prompted me to check the configuration of maven-surefire-plugin in my pom.

After removing a few unnecessary configs, it started working through maven. Then I reloaded the project through IntelliJ and now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out there were a few issues (some of them are likely not related to the specific question, but still best practices).
What helped for me was:

1. Consolidate dependency management of JUnit by importing junit-bom
2. Upgrading maven-surefire-plugin to latest version
3. Removing unnecessary configs from maven-surefire-plugin (my configuration tag is now empty)
4. Reloading the project in IntelliJ (Right click project -> Maven -> Reload project)

Thanks a lot to [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) and [Kathrin Geilmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15133183/kathrin-geilmann) for the help :)